# after page load expanded li's are not preserving their state in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am developing one portal using angularjs. I have li's inside ul. I am binding data to li's using loop. My problem is that for example i will click on some li inside ul page works fine with related data but if i refresh the page i will not be in same li i was before page load. For example, I have below code,

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-if="project">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" ng-href="{{'#!/p/' + project.key + '/'}}"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-heading pull-left" ng-bind="project.name"></div>
  <div ng-if="project.logoFile" class="client-logo pull-right"><img ng-src="{{project.logoFile.url}}"/></div>
  <!-- Top Menu Items -->
  <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav public">
      <li>
        <a ng-href="{{'#!/p/' + project.key + '/'}}"><img src="images/icons/visible.png"/> Project Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a ng-href="{{'#!/p/' + project.key + '/procedure'}}"><img src="images/icons/recycle_sign.png"/> Procedure Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="p in processMenu" bs-collapse data-start-collapsed="true">
        <a ng-href="{{'#!/p/' +project.key + '/process/' + p.id}}">
          <img ng-src="{{p.iconFileobj.url}}" ng-if="p.iconFileobj.url"/> {{p.name}}
          <i ng-if="p.children && p.children.length > 0" class="down-arrow fa fa-caret-down" bs-collapse-toggle
            ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation()"></i>
        </a>
        <ul bs-collapse-target class="panel-collapse" ng-if="p.children && p.children.length > 0">
          <li ng-repeat="pr in p.children">
            <a ng-href="{{'#!/p/' +project.key + '/process/' + pr.id}}">
              <img ng-if="pr.iconFileobj.url" ng-src="{{pr.iconFileobj.url}}"/> {{pr.name}}
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>

<div id="page-wrapper" ng-if="project">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ol class="breadcrumb" ng-if="nav.breadcrumb && nav.breadcrumb.length > 0">
          <li ng-repeat="b in nav.breadcrumb" ng-class="{active: !b.href}">
            {{!b.href ? b.title : ''}}
            <a ng-href="{{b.href}}" ng-bind="b.title" ng-if="b.href"></a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" ui-view=""></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <div class="footer-copyright">&copy; 2017 All rights reserved to Norconsult Telematics</div>
</div>
<a ng-if="project" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="togglePageMenu()" class="page-link am-slide" ng-class="{active: pageMenuShown}">i</a>
<ul ng-if="pageList" class="page-menu am-slide-right" ng-show="pageMenuShown">
  <li ng-repeat="p in pageList">
    <a ng-href="{{'#!/p/' + project.key + '/page/' + p.id}}">
      <img ng-if="p.fileob" ng-src="{{p.fileob.url}}"/> <br/>
      {{p.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Below is my controller code.
/* Copyright 2017-Preset all rights reserved*/

```
(function(guiApp) {
  'use strict';

  guiApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('public.process', {
      url: '/process/:processId',
      templateUrl: 'views/public/process.html',
      controller: 'PublicProcessController',
    });
  });

  guiApp.controller('PublicProcessController', function($scope, $stateParams, AppConfig, processService) {
    $scope.setAtiveProcess($stateParams.processId);
    $scope.currentProcess = $scope.processList.filter(function(process) {
      return parseInt(process.id) === parseInt($stateParams.processId);
    })[0];

    if (!$scope.currentProcess) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.filteredTemplates = function(processId) {
      var templates = $scope.processTemplates.filter(function(templateWrapper) {
        return(processId == templateWrapper.processId);
      });

      return templates;
    };

    $scope.processTemplates = [];
    processService.getTemplates($scope.currentProcess.id).then(function(res) {
      var templates = res.data;

      templates.forEach(function(template) {
        template.filesObj.url = AppConfig.uploadsBaseUrl + template.filesObj.url;
        $scope.processTemplates.push({ processId: $scope.currentProcess.id, data: template });
      });
    });

    if($scope.currentProcess.children) {
      $scope.currentProcess.children.forEach(function(childProcess) {
        processService.getTemplates(childProcess.id).then(function(res) {
          var templates = res.data;

          templates.forEach(function(template) {
            template.filesObj.url = AppConfig.uploadsBaseUrl + template.filesObj.url;
            $scope.processTemplates.push({ processId: childProcess.id, data: template });
          });
        });
      });
    }

    $scope.settings = $scope.projectSettings.filter(function(item) {
      return item.level === $scope.currentProcess.level;
    })[0];

    $scope.level3Settings = $scope.projectSettings.filter(function(item) {
      return item.level === 3;
    })[0];


    $scope.setBreadcrumb([{ title: 'Project', href: '#!/p/' + $scope.project.key + '/' },
      { title: $scope.currentProcess.name }
    ]);

    $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.checkVal = !$scope.checkVal; // or false
    angular.element('#flowChartCheckbox').trigger('click');
  };
  });
})(window.guiApp);
```

Please look into this
http://35.161.147.179/#!/p/Al-Khobar-Power-Plant-Project/process/81

In the above link if i click on allocate budjet i will get respective data and if i click on f5 i will be left with blank. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you preserving the data? When you reload the page, you'll lose the transient state data (like an object with properties the user set one way or another) unless you write them durably somewhere, like local storage, a cookie, or the the route (url) somehow. I had a similar problem, I solved it by writing the info the URL instead of just obtaining it from a service (since the service is wiped when reinitialized).

Comment: Thank you. I am getting from api's. On page load i willbe calling api's.

Comment: Where you're getting it isn't the issue, where you're putting it, and how you are grabbing it again when the page reloads, is the question. Are you putting the data anywhere durable, or just saving it in memory in the running app? When you refresh the page (browser refresh), you basically reinitialize the whole thing. But say you collected that data in an object of some kind, you could write it to a cookie, local storage (serialized as JSON, whatever), whatever, then you could check for it on page reload, and if anything is there, load it into the app and use it.

Comment: Actually i am trying to alter code written by someone else. I will paste what i have in controller.

Comment: The data I'm talking about isn't your API data btw. It's the data you want to preserve that will allow you to reconstitute the page exactly as the user last saw it. This could be as simple as collecting style information (like which divs were hidden/shown) and persisting it temporarily.

Comment: Looks like everything is just loaded into the scope, which will wipe on a refresh. You'll need to implement a way to persist the data you'd need to reconstitute the page, and then access that data when the page reinitializes; cookie, local storage, url, something.

Comment: May i get some help on this?

Comment: Search for "browser local storage". You will see. It's easy. Again, there's other ways, but this is as good as any to get you rolling.